# Google won't index my newly created home page after I had used a removal request for the default WordPress site on my domain

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, crawl-errors

I have a site built with WordPress. Initially, because the default content of the template was indexed in Google, I decided to remove those URLs through the removals section in the Google console search. I also enabled the nofollow and noindex tags for all posts and tabs via the Yoast plugin.

After that, when I searched `site:example.com`, there were no search results. When I tried to index the home page again from the Google console search, `https://example.com`, I came across a noindex error while I had previously removed the tags.

Other pages do not provide this error, but I Google Search Console live test reports that the page "will be indexed only if certain conditions are met"

I don't know why in the beginning, even though I didn't create a sitemap, everything was normal and the pages were indexed quickly, but after I deleted the previous URLs and added new ones, the pages don't index. Of course, the last time Google crawled the home page was on May 26.

Comment: This may be hard to recover from.   It was a mistake to use a removal request.  It would have been better to just replace the default site with your own content and let Googlebot re-crawl it and update the index.   Now Google thinks you don't want to have your site indexed.   I'm not sure what you can do to help in this situation.  Hopefully somebody else here will have answers for you.

Comment: A sitemap has very little to do with SEO.  Googlebot is fully capable of discovering and crawling your site even without one.   A sitemap can get Google to come crawl the URLs listed in it and it can be a signal about which URLs are correct when you have the same content on two URLs.   However sitemaps don't usually help get your content indexed and ranked, nor do they limit what is indexed to just what is in the sitemap.  Very few sites actually benefit from having a sitemap, especially when they are based on a good crawlable CMS like WordPress.

Comment: If I remove all remove requests from removal, might it be fixed?

Comment: It would be worth a try.

Comment: thanks for your help. The new question is, does it matter which page I deleted? I mean, if I delete, for example, example.com/blog, and then create a new page with URL example.com/mag, will I still have the same problem? (My domain and site age is about 3 weeks, and when I created the entire page, I then tagged the meta tag - robots as "index - follow")